# Log file cannot hold more data for that day

Tags: logging, log4j

I have this Log4j.properties with me

```
log4j.rootCategory=Info, A1

# A1 is a DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.file=${user.home}/MYWEB/MYWEB.log
log4j.appender.A1.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A1.append=true
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-22d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %m%n
```

My question is that , the Log file MYWEB.log is not able to hold more data , means if more requests are made to the application , the Previous logs are being lost .

Please tell me how to make the Log file hold any amount of daat for that day .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a plain RollingFileAppender

```
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=10MB
```

etc

[How do you get log4j to roll files based on date and size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794987/how-do-you-get-log4j-to-roll-files-based-on-date-and-size) points to an appender that uses both time and size

Comment: Thank you very much , but i want to use DailyRollingFileAppender because it comes nicely date wise and when i tried the above  option with DailyRollingFileAppender it gave me no such attribute .