# Log4j and Logback FileAppender maxFileSize and maxBackupIndex

Tags: java, log4j, logback, log4j2, fileappender

I need to control the maximum amount of disk space for my logging framework.
For instance, in log4j, I can easily estimate how much disk space I need if I have an appender like this:

```
<appender name="appender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="file" value="example.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p %t %c - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
</appender>
```

With maxFileSize and maxBackupIndex I know I'll need at most 10x100KB.
I've noticed DailyRollingFileAppender but it doesn't support maxFileSize.

Are there other FileAppenders than RollingFileAppender that can achieve this control? 
Does logback or log4j2 provide other FileAppenders/alternatives?

**Note:** I'm looking for ways of configuring the logging framework only, no external processes like crontab with rm command. 3rd party FileAppenders like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983454/2838491), [this](http://haobangshou.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hbs/APPLICATION/server/common/src/com/hbs/common/appender/TimeSizeRollingFileAppender.java) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848091/2838491) are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does logback or log4j2 provide other FileAppenders/alternatives

log4j2 introduces `RandomAccessFileAppender` and `RollingRandomAccessFileAppender` which are still experimental, may replace `FileAppender` and `RollingFileAppender` in a future release. [See here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender).

However current [`RollingFileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) requires a `TriggeringPolicy`:

- **OnStartup Triggering Policy**: The OnStartup policy takes no parameters and causes a rollover if the log file is older than the current JVM's start time.
- **SizeBased Triggering Policy**: Causes a rollover once the file has reached the specified size. The size can be specified in bytes, KB, MB or GB.
- **TimeBased Triggering Policy**: Causes a rollover once the date/time pattern no longer applies to the active file. This policy accepts an "increment" attribute which indicates how frequently the rollover should occur based on the time pattern and a "modulate" boolean attribute.

Comment: I agree that the SizeBased triggering policy is probably what cenoura is looking for. Just for completeness, both RollingFileAppender and RollingRandomAccessFileAppender support the same triggering policies.

Comment: Yes, it seems to do the trick. Even if using `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` and `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` together with a `DefaultRolloverStrategy`, I guess I could estimate the maximum disk usage, since the `DefaultRolloverStrategy` would limit the number of files.

@Sage thanks for pointing the `RandomAccessFileAppender` and `RollingRandomAccessFileAppender`. Looks like they perform much better than RollingFileAppender.

Comment: Exactly. Though they are still experimental. Sorry i should have mentioned the Rollover strategy too. :(