# How to change log4j roll over file name format?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I Have following log4j RollingFileAppender based on file size. I wanted to customize the roll over file names. The following snippet producing the following filenames

```
test.log
test.log.1
test.log.2
```

But, I wanted to customize it to include the date and time such as

```
test.log
test.log.2017-10-03-14-00
test.log.2017-10-03-13-00
test.log.2017-10-03-12-00
```

---

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="10KB" />
    <param name="File" value="log/test.log" />
    <param name="threshold" value="info" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] HH:mm:ss]} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Can some one guide me how to do that ?

Comment: So you want unlimited number of files?

Comment: limitted to 10 just for an ex

Answer (score 0):

You should use `org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender` instead

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="log/test.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm"/>
    ...
</appender>
```

You may also check on

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Seems like https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html may provide you with the functionality you seek.

Comment: That creates a log file every minute right. But I want to limit to file size and roll over file to be rename to include date and time

Comment: I think you will have to code it yourself in this case. Please check on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794987/how-do-you-get-log4j-to-roll-files-based-on-date-and-size